# How to Apply unnest_tokens to a Dataframe (Tibble) while Keeping the rest of the Data Intact?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

**Background Information**

I have a 584 x 4 tibble (`dat_text_tb`).  As shown in the photo below, this contains one character column(`text`), where each one of the 584 texts I collected is respectively stored:

[image: This image shows the structure of the dataframe]

**What I intend to accomplish**

The next step for me would be to tokenize the content of each cell in this column (i.e., `text`) into a word vector by using `unnest_tokens()`.

**How I proceeded**

I used the following code:

```
dat_word_tb <- dat_text_tb %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

**The error message (shown in red on the console)**

```
Error in unnest_tokens(., word, text) : 
  could not find function "unnest_tokens"
```

**Any guidance on where the problem is and on how to move forward is more than welcome**

Gratefully,
Á_C

Comment: Have you installed and loaded the package `tidytext`?

Comment: I hadn't.  Thank you @deschen.  Out of embarrassment; i feel compelled to explain that I thought it loaded automatically as a component of ```tidyverse```.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, when loading the tidyverse package, you‘ll get a message about which packages are included. tidytext is not part of it.